# No module named 'transformer_base'

Tags: nlp, summarization, huggingface-transformers

I face this problem when i try to run bart_sum from huggingface transformers. I'm not sure what this module use. I have tried !pip install transformers, and the !python setup.py develop inside the transformers directory, and then !pip install -r requirements.txt inside the examples directory. Here's a screenshot: [The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWkQD.png)

Could someone please help me out?

Comment: Have you tried a relative import from the package you're currently running? `transformer_base` is located in the top level of the examples folder, and should be possible to import if you have done a from source installation.

Comment: @dennlinger I tried both sys.path.insert and os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] += but didn't have any luck. I'm trying this in colab btw, does colab handle things differently?

Answer (score 0):

You can try appending the path of transformers_base to sys.path.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "path to transformers_base")
```

Comment: I tried both sys.path.insert and os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] += but didn't have any luck. I'm trying this in colab btw, does colab handle things differently?